# ffmpeg - How does avcodec_decode_video2 work?

Tags: ffmpeg

As we know, one **AVPacket** contains one **AVFrame**, and we can use

```
int avcodec_decode_audio4(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *frame,
                          int *got_frame_ptr, const AVPacket *avpkt)
```

to decode a packet to frame, if it works, `got_frame_ptr` will be set with nonzero, otherwise, it's zero.

```
int len = avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
if ( len < 0 )
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Problems decoding frame\n");
    return 1;
}

fprintf(stderr, "len = %d\n", len );

// Did we get a video frame?
if(frameFinished) {
    dosomething();
}
```

How would it fail(`got_frame_ptr` is 0)? Is the **AVPacket** we got corrupted or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 2 main reasons (apart from error)

1. The current frame is a future P-Frame, hence this cannont be retured (displayed) now. This happens in case of B-frames in the sequence.
2. The current packet is not a complete decodable frame.

Comment: The delay also happens when multithreaded decoding is used. Regarding B-frames, their presence is not necessary: it is enough for an h264 stream to declare "max b-frames=3" to cause 3 frames delay in avcodec_decode_video2()